# Jinja 2 - ignoring dashes but still processing field?

Tags: python, jinja2, identifier

Good afternoon,

I have the below Jinja field:

```
{{ DEVICE_RTR-02:LOOPBACK_SUBNET }}
```

When this filename runs through the render

```
expected token 'end of print statement', got ':'
```

so I swapped the : for a ++ instead and then I get

```
'DEVICE_RTR' is undefined
```

Which to me looks like its taking the dash symbol as a function possibly?

I tried escaping it as per the below, that just ignores the whole field

```
{{ 'DEVICE_RTR-02++LOOPBACK_SUBNET' }}
```

I need to use a separator char which I split against in my function to get the right data. and the - is how the data is named.

is there a way to escape all chars but process the data in it? or does anyone know what values I can swap to make this work?

background function is below, which should give an idea of what im doing:

```
field_names = re.findall(r'(?s)(?<={{)(.*?)(?=}})', template.config, flags=re.S)
for i, field in enumerate(field_names):
    data = field
    data = data.strip()
    data = data.lower()
    if '|' in data:
        data = data.split('|')[0]
    field_names[i] = data

field_names = list(set(field_names))
template_data = {}
for name in field_names:
    # reset the device_data incase it was altered with the alt name
    device_data = Device.objects.get(id=device_id)
    if '++' in name:
        alt_data = name.split('++')[0]
        if alt_data.startswith('device_'):
            alt_data = alt_data.split('_')
            device_data = Device.objects.get(site_id=device_data.site_id,hostname__icontains=alt_data[1])    
            alt_field_data = get_field_data(name.split('++')[1])

            alt_field_data[name.upper()] = alt_field_data.pop(name.split('++')[1].upper())
            template_data = {**template_data, **alt_field_data}
        else:
            template_data = {**template_data, **get_field_data(name.split('++')[1])}
    else:
        template_data = {**template_data, **get_field_data(name)}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using `-` and `:`? None of which are valid in a python identifier

Comment: if you see the function, i am breaking that filename up to perform actions on it. the dash is used a fieldname from the db. the colon I used to split the name up to get parts I need. ive swapped that for ++ which works for now, but the dash is causing issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fields are processed because the regex you use to match them is `(.*?)` which matches *anything*. But, the [Jinja2 docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/api/#notes-on-identifiers) say that identifiers are matched using this regex:

```
[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*
```

So I guess your only option is use the underscore as "control character". One possible solution could be the following.

### When the template is generated

At the moment of generating the Jinja2 **template fields**, use:

- **double** underscores (`__`) in place of the dash (`-`);
- **triple** underscores (`___`) as a separator, instead of `++`;
- **one** underscore as device name separator (like you already do).

### Parsing the template

You can replace the for loop in the above Python code like e.g.:

```
for name in field_names:
    # reset the device_data incase it was altered with the alt name
    device_data = Device.objects.get(id=device_id)
    if '___' in name: # look for separator
        alt_data = name.split('___')[0]
        if alt_data.startswith('device_'):
            hname = alt_data[7:] # this line has changed
            device_data = Device.objects.get(site_id=device_data.site_id,hostname__icontains=hname)    
            alt_field_data = get_field_data(name.split('___')[1])

            alt_field_data[name.upper()] = alt_field_data.pop(name.split('___')[1].upper())
            template_data = {**template_data, **alt_field_data}
        else:
            template_data = {**template_data, **get_field_data(name.split('___')[1])}
    else:
        template_data = {**template_data, **get_field_data(name)}
```

Comment: this wont quite work. as the original name is used in dictionary key when loaded into the template, but we've just changed it to have dashes and plus in

Comment: Then the problem is, you are using an invalid key for the template. Identifiers cannot use +,-,., :etc.: they'll be parsed as operators. You should encode them before adding them to the jinja2 template.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, however we would still be in the same situation this would create a dictionary that works, but the template would not as the template has the fields 'DEVICE_RTR-02++LOOPBACK_SUBNET' in it whilst the dictionary would have DEVICE_RTR___02__LOOPBACK_SUBNET so it wouldn't match

Comment: @AlexW Not if you use the dictionary to populate the template fields.

Comment: sorry I don't feel I've explained the issue correctly. The dictionary is generated by gathering field names from the template. The dict is then created dynamically and the dict and the template are combined and sent to the user

Comment: @AlexW ok. What/who generates the template? Since no punctuation is allowed in jinja2 fields, it must be told not to put the wrong chars in there.

Comment: So the template is created by a user selecting fields from a drop down on a webpage (I can set the fields to whatever it needs to be set to). then if a user wants to generate against the template, a user click will call a function to get the template fields, create a dict then return a completed template to the user

Comment: one more edit needed to turn the __ into a dash hname = hname.replace('__','-') but it works, thankyou